# How can you tell a zone is depleted?

Tags: die2nite

Is it after searching a few times and not finding anything, or is it automatically marked after enough auto searches?

I know you can mark it while in the zone, but how do I know WHEN to mark it depleted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a some searches of the zone, it will show you this text, above the search button. Which indicates that the zone is depleted

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It'll say it above the search button when it's depleted, and then you have to manually mark it depleted under the map to show it to others. It'll look something like this:
[image]